# Rails Updating A Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have database table called managers and here is the corresponding section for schema.rb

```
 create_table "managers", force: true do |t|
t.string   "fname"
t.string   "lname"
t.string   "company"
t.string   "phone"
t.string   "cell"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "plan_id"
t.string   "country"
t.string   "address"
t.string   "timezone"
t.string   "zipcode",     default: "0"
t.datetime "open_time"
t.datetime "close_time"
t.integer  "shifts"
t.integer  "shiftlength"
  end
```

In my controller I am trying to update it by calling the update action

```
def update
   @manager=Manager.find(params[:id])
   if @manager.update(manager_params)
     redirect_to manager_path(:id=>params[:id])
   else
     render action: 'edit'
   end
 end

 def manager_params
    params.require(:manager).permit :fname,
   :lname,
    :company,
   :country,
   :address,
   :timezone,
   :zipcode,
   :phone,
   :cell,
   :open_time,
   :close_time,:shifts,:shiftlength
 end
```

But the update action throws the following error

undefined method `each' for "4":String

The values :shifts and :shiftlength are being taken from number input fields. I tried to convert :shifts and :shiftlengths to integers using to_i but that did not work.

It then gave the error

undefined method `each' for 4:Fixnum

Relevant section of update form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%=m.label :number_of_shifts%><br />
    <%= m.number_field :shifts,:class=>"form-control",:value=>@manager.shifts %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <%=m.label :shift_length%><br />
    <%= m.number_field :shiftlength,:class=>"form-control",:value=>@manager.shiftlength   %>
</div>
```

Comment: What line exactly is giving you the undefined method error?

Comment: On which line did you got that error?

Comment: @Micah error occurs on manager.update

Comment: Ok show your manager model please.

Comment: @Micah I can show you model but that is not relevant here as attributes_accesible is deprecated and that function has been moved to controller

Comment: Okay everyone I couldn't find the solution but have found a work around

    manager_attributes=manager_params
    manager_attributes.each do |k,v|
      @manager[k]=v
    end
    if @manager.save
      Time.zone=@manager.timezone
      redirect_to manager_path(:id=>params[:id])
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end